# Unable to use API Gateway with gzip

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have setup API gateway with an API that returns JSON via Lambda integration.

When I tried to make a GET call through the browser, I received the errors
`ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` on Chrome and `NSURLErrorDomain:-1015` on Safari.

When I made a GET call using `curl`, I was able to get the response.

On searching around, I found that the problem is with gzip. It appeared that the browsers send a header indicating that they accept gzip, but are unable to handle the response. When I tried making the curl command using `--compressed`, I received a similar error.

To resolve this, I tried to enable 'Content Encoding enabled' on API Gateway with minimum size as 0 bytes. This did not solve the problem.

While trying to make the `curl` call with `-compressed` flag, I passed the header 'Accept-Encoding' and set it to ''. This gave me a valid response.

Eventually, I am using AngularJS to make HTTP calls. I tried to set the header as above, but Angular doesn't allow it. (Gives an error `Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"`)

Can someone help me understand how I can get around this problem?

Comment: The symptoms you describe would be the *exact* expected behavior if you are setting the response header to `Content-Encoding: gzip` but are not actually gzipping the response body *or* if you are returning gzipped content in a context where API Gateway assumes your response is text/not binary and you are not base64-encoding it and having API Gateway do the transformation back to binary.  Setting the header doesn't do anything other than to indicate that the body is gzipped... so how is your content getting gzipped?

Comment: Thank you so much! I had enabled 'compression' in my ExpressJS code which was causing this problem. I removed it and the problem is gone. Please write this as the answer so that I can accept it and mark the question as resolved.